# My lease agreement has a typo that changes the intended meaning

Tags: tenant, residential-lease, lease, tenancy-rules, breaking-the-lease

I'm in New York. I share this lease with a roommate who is also on the lease but is leaving a month after I am. Our lease that states "After the initial term of this Agreement, or in case of a month-to-month tenancy, the TENANT may terminate the Lease with a minimum of calendar days written notice."

I assume here that the lease is just missing an exact number? But does this mean I don't have to give 30 days notice? It also states "The TENANT shall vacate the premises upon termination of the Agreement, unless the LANDLORD accepts further rent from the TENANT (other than past due rent), in which case a month-to-month tenancy shall be created which either party may terminate by a thirty (30) day written notice."

Does the mention of 30 days here negate the other sentence?

Answer (score 1):

### The TENANT is both of you

The TENANT (i.e. both of you) have to give 30 days notice. And the TENANT (again, both of you) must “ vacate the premises upon termination of the Agreement, unless …”.

Answer (score 0):

> does this mean I don't have to give 30 days notice?

You and your roommate are renting the premises jointly.  You cannot terminate the agreement unilaterally.  You need the agreement of the other parties to modify the lease.

As far as the landlord is concerned, the two of you are jointly and severally liable for the rent through the end of the month in which he regains possession of the apartment, or the first month end that falls 30 days or more after he learns of your intention to relinquish possession, whichever is later.  So no, you don't have to give 30 days notice.  The 30 days notice of your roommate's departure is sufficient.

> Does the mention of 30 days here negate the other sentence?

The other sentence doesn't specify a number of days, so this sentence isn't in conflict with it.  If the other sentence specified a different number of days, there would be a conflict.

If the lease didn't specify a number of days anywhere then the statutory notice period applying to month to month tenancies would apply, which is, if I recall correctly, 30 days.